# Creating post web api 2 actions

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am currently attempting to do something that should be fairly straight forward, but to be honest is pretty far from it at the moment and its driving me a bit mad.

I've been consuming Get actions in my WebApi, however I'm trying to create Post actions in order to keep my mvc controllers clean however I can't for the life of me figure out why my get actions work as expected but my post action results in a 404

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using TamWeb.Models.api;

namespace TamWeb.Controllers.api
{
    [Authorize]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class AdminController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public bool UpdateDetails([FromBody]DetailsViewModel model)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

using System;

namespace TamWeb.Models.api
{
    public class DetailsViewModel
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The api controller is as simple as it gets and as per several other api questions instead of using string parameters I've created a model object and to follow other answers and what little out of date documentation I can find I consume the api as follows:

```
$(function() {
    var firstname = $('#firstName').val();
    var lastname = $('#lastName').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "api/admin/UpdateDetails",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify([firstname, lastname]),
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function() { console.log("error") }
    });
});
```

As far as I can tell everything "should" work, however fiddler keeps telling me the url doesn't exist so now I'm at a loss as to whats wrong.

Comment: Have you tried with `url: "api/admin"`?

Answer (score 0):

hopefully my answer can help you to deal with your question.
1.first issue you have to use "ApiController" instead "Controller"
2. [Authorize] <-- you have to get token key and then using it to get data from webapi

as following code, I will share you me simple code without Authorize,I wish it can solve your problems
client code

```
$("#read1").click(function () {    
      $.support.cors = true;
      $.ajax({
          crossDomain: true,
          url: 'http://localhost:43520/api/Banners/',
          datatype: "json",
          contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          data: { id: 123 },
          type: 'post',          
          error: function (xhr, status, errorThrow) {
              alert(xhr.status);
          },
          success: function (data) {
              alert(JSON.stringify(data));
          }
      });
  });
```

server code

```
 // GET: api/Banners/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(Banners))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetBanners(int id)
        {
            Banners banners = db.Banners.Find(id);
            if (banners == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(banners);
        }
```